# How to find item using wildcard in Kendo AutoComple

Tags: kendo-ui, kendo-autocomplete

I am using Kendo with JQuery, And I need to create a search with wildcard

Ex:   Apple%Red

How I can I do this?

Comment: You need to provide more details as who is going to run the search the browser or the backend services.

Comment: Which `Kendo UI for ...` or `Telerik UI for ...` product are you using ?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Despite that I cannot find any reference to it in the documentation of [autocomplete](https://docs.telerik.com/kendo-ui/api/javascript/ui/autocomplete) and it says [filter](https://docs.telerik.com/kendo-ui/api/javascript/ui/autocomplete/configuration/filter) needs to be `String` you can define it as a `function` that receives two parameters, the item to compare with and the value of the input field.

Now, the question is that given that you use `%` as a wildcard, makes me think that you should be using a server-side filtering but given that you ask for a JavaScript or jQuery implementation makes me think you ask for a browser implementation.

If your users can enter the wildcards using JavaScript regular expression syntax, you can simply do:

```
$("#autocomplete").kendoAutoComplete({
  filter: function(input, pattern) {
    var re = new RegExp(pattern, 'i');
    return re.test(input);
  },
  dataSource: {
    data: ["one", "two", "three"]
  }
});
```

But if you want them to use `%` as wildcard for any character you can internally replace if by `.*` and do something like:

```
$("#autocomplete").kendoAutoComplete({
  filter: function(input, pattern) {
    pattern = pattern.replace('%', '.*');
    var re = new RegExp(pattern, 'i';
    return re.test(input);;
  },
  dataSource: {
    data: ["One", "Two", "Three"]
  }
});
```

**NOTE**: Important to note that by default autocomplete is case insensitive but you can control it using [ignoreCase](https://docs.telerik.com/kendo-ui/api/javascript/ui/autocomplete/configuration/ignorecase)

Following a code snippet. Try entering `t` and `t%e`

```js
var ignoreCase = true;
$("#autocomplete").kendoAutoComplete({
  ignoreCase: ignoreCase,
  filter: function(input, pattern) {
    pattern = pattern.replace('%', '.*');
    var re = new RegExp(pattern, ignoreCase ? 'i' : '');
    return re.test(input);
  },
  dataSource: {
    data: ["One", "Two", "Three"]
  }
});
```

```html
<link rel="stylesheet" href="https://kendo.cdn.telerik.com/2018.1.221/styles/kendo.common.min.css" />
<link rel="stylesheet" href="https://kendo.cdn.telerik.com/2018.1.221/styles/kendo.silver.min.css" />
<script src="https://code.jquery.com/jquery-1.12.4.min.js"></script>
<script src="https://kendo.cdn.telerik.com/2018.1.221/js/kendo.all.min.js"></script>

<input id="autocomplete" />
```

Comment: Great! Thanks... but just work with one time.. T%e%e not work

Comment: If you can use more than one `%` then you should use `pattern.replace(/%/g, '.*');` instead of `pattern.replace('%', '.*');`

Comment: Super, you are the best!!